# In Multisite setup the custom page '/speakers' should available on domain1 site only

Tags: routes, multi-sites

I have Multi-site setup , want to make available custom page say '/speakers' on domain1 site but not on domain2 site

I have tried to figured out in routing.yml file to check is there way to pass any variable in route where I can define that route should available for specific domain only,
even I tried with the alter routes approach as well but no luck.

**Note: Both sites has same custom module installed.**

Comment: Does this mean each site has the same custom module installed that provides the route? If so the question is missing that information.

Comment: Yes , both sites has same custom module installed, updated that missing info.

Comment: One solution is not to install the module on some sites. Another is to define the route dynamically in PHP.

Comment: Yet another is to have the route controller return a 404 base on the request domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used kind of similar approach in which removed the route conditionally by using alter routes()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for record purpose, posting answer:

I used alter routes() approach in which used remove function w.r.t to domain condition:

```
  $collection->remove('route_name');
```

Created: module_name.services.yml (root of custom module)

```
module_name.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\module_name\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Created: RouteSubscriber.php (module_name\src\Routing)

```
<?php
  namespace Drupal\module_name\Routing;
  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

  class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
 
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      $domain = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
      // check domain
      if($domain == 'domain_name'){
        if ($collection->get('route_name')) {
          // remove route conditionally
          $collection->remove('route_name');
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Info: I Choose this particular approach becoz I need to enabled same module for both sites

To get more info related to routes, [visit to this documentation link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes) on official site of DRUPAL